MUI 5 styled Button missing props
I'm trying to implement a MUI5-based styled button in a separate component like this:
import {Button, buttonClasses, ButtonProps, styled} from '@mui/material';

interface MxFlatButtonProps extends Omit<ButtonProps, 'size' | 'variant'> {
}

const DEFAULT_PROPS: ButtonProps = {
    variant: 'text',
    size: 'medium',
    color: 'primary'
};

const StyledFlatButton = styled(Button)(({theme: {spacing}}) => ({
    minWidth: 'auto',
    lineHeight: 1,
    // a bit more styles
}));


export const MxFlatButton = (props: MxFlatButtonProps) =>
    <StyledFlatButton
        {...DEFAULT_PROPS}
        {...props}
    />;

It works fine until I applied component and to props than worked fine with pure MUI Button component.
Here I get an error:
import {Link as RouterLink, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

// some code skipped

<MxFlatButton
    component={RouterLink}
    to='someLink'
>
    Some text
</MxFlatButton>


The error is folliwing:
TS2322: Type

{
     children: string;
     component: <S = unknown>(props: LinkProps<S> & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>) => ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | null;
     to: string;
}


is not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes & MxFlatButtonProps
    Property to does not exist on type IntrinsicAttributes & MxFlatButtonProps


Versions are following:
"@mui/material": "5.15.15",
"@mui/styles": "5.15.15",
"react-router": "^5.1.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"

What am I missing? I supposed that styled button would inherit props from MUI Button, but I was wrong.

I cant give you an definite answer, but I can tell you there is nothing wrong with your styled component, you do everything right. Take a look at this code which is working as expected:
"use client";

import { MxFlatButton } from "@/components/test";
// import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <main>
            <div>main</div>
            <MxFlatButton component={Link} href="google">
                Some Text
            </MxFlatButton>
        </main>
    );
}

Because I am on next js, I use the Link from nextjs routing. But the Code above is working as expected! This indicates, that the props are passed correctly to the style component.
Why doesnt it work with Link from react-router-dom? I am not sure, but if you try instead of to, the href as an prop, it would give more information about the problem.
